# ¿Cómo hacer funcionar este juego de piedra papel tijera lagarto spock?

Tags: python

estoy tratando de hacer un juego de piedra papel tijera lagarto spock, sin embargo no e conseguido que me de una respuesta de cual es le ganador

```
class juego:
  def jugar(player_1,player_2):
    player_1 = index(opciones)
    player_2 = index(opciones)
    opciones = [piedra, papel, tijera, lagarto, spock]


  def determinar_ganador(player_1,player_2):
      if player_1 == player_2:
        print("empate")
     
      elif player_1 == "papel":
        if player_2 == "piedra" or player_2 == "spock":
          print("jugador 1 gana")
        else:
            print("jugador 2 gana")
      elif player_1 == "lagarto":
        if player_2 == "papel" or player_2 == "spock":
          print("jugador 1 gana")
        else:
          print("jugador 2 gana")
      elif player_1 == "spock":
        if player_2 == "piedra" or player_2 == "tijeras":
            print("jugador 1 gana")
        else:
          print("jugador 2 gana")
      

player_1 = input("Ingresa el valor que elije el jugador 1: ")
player_2 = input("Ingresa el valor que elije el jugador 2: ")
```

no e podido hacer que me de resultado, e tratado de hacer varios intentos sin embrago no e podido desarrollarlo, soy novato en esto de la programación y la verdad necesito ayuda para entender el por que no me da el resultado

Answer (score 2):

1. Tu envolviste un función en una clase, por lo que el primer argumento de esa función debe ser `self`

```
def determinar_ganador(self,player_1,player_2):
```

2. Tienes que instanciar la case y llamar a la función

```
game = juego()
game.determinar_ganador(player_1,player_2)
```

3. Te faltan `elif` para lo casos de piedra y tijera

```
class juego:
    def determinar_ganador(self,player_1,player_2):
        if player_1 == player_2:
            print("empate")
        elif player_1 == "papel":
            if player_2 == "piedra" or player_2 == "spock":
                print("jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("jugador 2 gana")
        elif player_1 == "lagarto":
            if player_2 == "papel" or player_2 == "spock":
                print("jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("jugador 2 gana")
        elif player_1 == "spock":
            if player_2 == "piedra" or player_2 == "tijera":
                print("jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("jugador 2 gana")
        elif player_1 == "tijera":
            if player_2 == "papel" or player_2 == "lagarto":
                print("jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("jugador 2 gana")
        elif player_1 == "piedra":
            if player_2 == "lagarto" or player_2 == "tijera":
                print("jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("jugador 2 gana")


player_1 = input("Ingresa el valor que elije el jugador 1: ")
player_2 = input("Ingresa el valor que elije el jugador 2: ")

game = juego()
game.determinar_ganador(player_1,player_2)
```

Otra forma de hacer esto es crear un diccionario

```
ganadores={
"spock"  : ["tijera","piedra"], #spock gana a tijera y piedra
"tijera" : ["papel","lagarto"],  #tijera gana a papel y lagarto
"papel"  : ["piedra","spock"], #etc
"piedra" : ["lagarto","tijera"],
"lagarto": ["spock","papel"]
}

def determinar_ganador(player_1,player_2):
    if player_1 == player_2:
        print("empate")
    elif player_2 in ganadores[player_1]:
         print("Gana player 1")
    else:
         print("Gana player 2")

player_1 = input("Ingresa el valor que elije el jugador 1: ")
player_2 = input("Ingresa el valor que elije el jugador 2: ")

determinar_ganador(player_1,player_2)
```

Answer (score -1):

El error en la lógica del código se encuentra en este método.

```
def determinar_ganador(player_1, player_2):
    if player_1 == player_2:
        print("empate")
     
    elif player_1 == "papel":
        if player_2 == "piedra" or player_2 == "spock":
            print("jugador 1 gana")
        else:
            print("jugador 2 gana")
    elif player_1 == "lagarto":
        if player_2 == "papel" or player_2 == "spock":
            print("jugador 1 gana")
        else:
            print("jugador 2 gana")
    elif player_1 == "spock":
        if player_2 == "piedra" or player_2 == "tijeras":
            print("jugador 1 gana")
        else:
            print("jugador 2 gana")
```

En este fragmento de código, lo que se está haciendo es comparar las elecciones del `jugador 1` con las elecciones del `jugador 2`.

La lógica correcta es comparar las elecciones del `jugador 1` con las elecciones realizadas por el `jugador 2` y mostrar quién ganó.

`Primero` hay que verificar si las elecciones de los jugadores son iguales y, si lo son, hay un empate.

`Según` las reglas del juego, se debe comparar la elección del `jugador 1` con las del `jugador 2` y mostrar el resultado del juego:

código corregido :

```
class Juego:
    def __init__(self, player_1, player_2):
        self.player_1 = player_1
        self.player_2 = player_2
        self.determinar_ganador()

    def determinar_ganador(self):
        if self.player_1 == self.player_2:
            print("Un lazo")
         
        elif self.player_1 == "papel":
            if self.player_2 == "piedra" or self.player_2 == "spock":
                print("el jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("el jugador 2 gana")
        elif self.player_1 == "lagarto":
            if self.player_2 == "papel" or self.player_2 == "spock":
                print("el jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("el jugador 2 gana")
        elif self.player_1 == "spock":
            if self.player_2 == "piedra" or self.player_2 == "tijera":
                print("el jugador 1 gana")
            else:
                print("el jugador 2 gana")
        else:
            print("Elección no válida"")

player_1 = input("Ingrese la elección del jugador 1: ")
player_2 = input("Ingrese la elección del jugador 2: ")

juego = Juego(player_1, player_2)
```

Para simplificar, utilicé el constructor `__init__` con los parámetros `player_1` y `player_2`.
Luego se llama al método d`eterminar_ganador()` para ver quién es el ganador basado en las reglas.

Comment: muchas gracias.